# issue in getting data with post method php

Tags: apache, cakephp, http-post, httprequest, postdata

I have created one website using cakephp and in that the form elements are dynamic. I have form in which around 400 radio buttons and text are is there. The form generates and submitted properly will all value in my local system.

When I test this functionality on live server, I am not getting data for all 400 radio button, It stops after around 250 or so. if I reduce the loop and do it under 200 than all works good.

As search on google i set post data size in php but it didn't worked.

If there is any kind of setting needs to make in the apache server related it please let me know.

Comment: Including the source code might help!

Comment: Thanks for reply.. I think its the some setting which i am missing in server as the code works fine in local system. consider its like loop of which generates radio button and textare for 400 times.

Comment: If you have increased `post_max_size` already, consider increasing the `max_input_time` as well.

Comment: max_input_time is set unlimited.. still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution..

We need to set the max_input_vars which is default 1000. It means we can only post 1000 element in one request. You need to add this in php.ini file

```
   max_input_vars = 3000
```

This will allow to post 3000 element from page.